# What are the possible ways to fix problems when the server change from http to https?

Tags: javascript, http, https

I am having an issue with a calculation operation I am working on since the server changes from http to https.

I haven't change anything in the file of the functionality giving the issues, and actually I don't know what is going on because the console is not returning any errors.

In the Production Environment everything works properly because the protocol is `http`, but in the Staging ENV, that part of the app goes down and is not returning anything due to the change to a secured server.

```
if(window.location.href.indexOf("standalone") != -1) {
  var pid = 'HL:Tool:HLmisc:Calc;MortgageCalculator';
  var standalone = 'standalone=y&';
}else{
  var pid = 'MHE:Tool:HLPE;Tool_AffordabilitySnapshot';
  var standalone = 'standalone=&';
}           if(window.location.href.indexOf("standalone") != -1) {
  var pid = 'HL:Tool:HLmisc:Calc;MortgageCalculator';
  var standalone = 'standalone=y&';
}else{
  var pid = 'MHE:Tool:HLPE;Tool_AffordabilitySnapshot';
  var standalone = 'standalone=&';
}

$(".submitBtn").click(function(e){
  //alert(this.id);
  var valRes = AFFSNAP.form.validate();
  if(this.id === 'incomeSubmit' && valRes) {
    //alert('build income array');
    var income = new Array();
    income['pid'] = pid+'Tool_AffordabilitySnapshot';
    income['nm'] = this.name;
    income['hr'] = location.protocol+'//'+location.hostname+location.pathname+'?'+standalone+'step=expenses&agi='+$('#agi').val()+'&mni='+$('#mni').val();
    AFFSNAP.throwManualCMClickEvt(income);
  }
  if(this.id === 'expensesSubmit' && valRes) {
    var expenses = new Array();
    expenses['pid'] = pid+'Tool_AFS_Expenses';
    expenses['nm'] = this.name;
    expenses['hr'] = '//'+location.hostname+location.pathname+'?'+standalone+'step=debt&utilities='+$('#utilities').val()+'&communications='+$('#communications').val()+'&entertainment='+$('#entertainment').val()+'&dependents='+$('#dependents').val()+'&travel='+$('#travel').val()+'&savings='+$('#savings').val();
    AFFSNAP.throwManualCMClickEvt(expenses);
  }
  if(this.id === 'calculateSubmit' && valRes){
    var calculate = new Array();
    calculate['pid'] = pid+'Tool_AFS_Debt';
    calculate['nm'] = this.name;
    calculate['hr'] = '//'+location.hostname+location.pathname+'?step=results&creditCards='+$('#creditCards').val()+'&loans='+$('#loans').val();
    AFFSNAP.throwManualCMClickEvt(calculate);
    AFFSNAP.throwCMOnLoadEvt2();
  }
  return valRes;
});
```

that is the function where it takes some of the input values and do the calculation I need.

Any suggestions?

**EDIT**
If you downvote, at least provide a reason so I can improve my answer. You are abusing of that functionality.

Comment: What is the error? "The app goes down" is by no means a failure description. So what exactly does not work?

Comment: What is AFFSNAP? If it involves some Ajax, you might have SOP problems. Make sure to serve your whole site via HTTPS.

Comment: [You're abusing `Array`s](http://andrewdupont.net/2006/05/18/javascript-associative-arrays-considered-harmful/).

Comment: @Bergi here is a Gist of that whole file https://gist.githubusercontent.com/maketroli/759b736d2af88653957ab5b88a1a37cb/raw/9a2115d2f8d40a65c11c0d6f683bc553db1baf53/AFFSNAP

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're referencing links within the same site, It's best to just reference paths relative to the root and omit the protocol & hostname. Your links would look like this:

```
<a href="/path/to/my/file.html?key1=val1">test</a>
```

The other way to handle it is to just remove the protocol altogether. This will allow it to be inherited from the current protocol. So your links would look like:

```
 <a href="//mydomain.com/path/to/my/file.html?key1=val1">test</a>
```

Whether your protocol is http or https, it will be automatically pre-pended to the href.